# How to update image using controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to update user image but it's not getting updated. I have used following controller for updating the image.. Can you suggest what's the mistake in controller function?

View part :

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Image Upload</label>
            <input type="file" name="image"  id="image"><img src="{{ asset('public/images/' . $course->image) }}" width="200px"/></br>
 </div>
```

Controller function :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data=Course::findOrFail($id);  


    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()); 
            $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $data->image = $name;
            $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);                       
        }   
             $data->course_code = $request['course_code'];
             $data->course_title = $request['course_title'];
             $data->course_credit = $request['course_credit'];

          $data->save();             
      return redirect('course');
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: I can't update actually ..

Comment: I get that... What *exactly* is the error? Like what does the error say lol...

Comment: Dude ..it's not showing any Error..just data not getting updated lol!

Comment: I see. That's helpful. You're gonna have to do some self-debugging then... Make sure the file is getting to the server, using `dd($variable);` where necessary, perhaps add a `try { } catch() { }` somewhere inside your `update()` function, etc etc. Hard to say what's going wrong otherwise.

Comment: see I dd() the output in array(0 I see the old image file only.new one not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked file permission on 'images' directory? It needs to have write permission for uploading files.

Comment: How do I check the permission?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this,

```
$data->image = $name;
```

You set the value but you don't save it anywhere. You must add a saving line.

```
$data->save();
```

Note that, calling `update()` only saves what you pass in as parameters, doesn't save what you set through the mutators.

Comment: I've updated the Question with your solution but still getting same Error..

Comment: what is the permission of the `public/images` directory?

Answer (score 0):

See The mistake/ solution of the problem is first i need to store the update value and then save the new image. So I made some changes in controller and solved it..

Here is controller code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data=Course::findOrFail($id);  
     $data->update($request->all());

    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()); 
            $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $data->image = $name;
            $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);   
            $data->save();                  
        }   
    return redirect('course');
}
```